# detect when anybody kills a zombie?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to know how to detect if a player kills a zombie so I can finish my game where zombies attempt to attack a castle and you have to defend it. I want to make so that when you kill 50 zombies you win the game.

if this is possible please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: i'm stuck at every part.

Comment: What part is, "every part"? What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: i'm stuck at every part and I used other posts on this website and other websites and they are all outdated.

Comment: So what is **every part**?  Show us what you've tried!  Not doing so makes it sound like you want us to do it all for you.

Comment: every part mean every part. duh

Comment: and i just said what i tried. OTHER POSTS.

Comment: What other posts?  Got some code?  **Show us what you've tried**.  Don't tell, **show**.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an objective of type `stat.killEntity.Zombie`, which will keep track of how many zombies the player has killed:

```
/scoreboard objectives add KillZombie stat.killEntity.Zombie
```

You can select people who have killed 50 zombies with `@a[score_KillZombie_min=50]`. For example, to teleport them somewhere:

```
/tp @a[score_KillZombie_min=50] X Y Z
```

Comment: ok. so, how to I set the score back to 0?

Comment: also, will "/title @a[score_KillZombie_min=50] Title [text:"you won!]" work?

Comment: nevermind I found out how to set it to zero